# How can I reliable match link, link_title and link_description

Tags: unificationengine

When parsing the message request object in my connector how can I reliable match a link to its title and description attribute? Are they always sorted in a special order in the parts array or is there only one link per message allowed?

I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in unificationengine, it seems that you can send only one link at a time by using v2/message/send api command.